# How do sites like codewars, that run user submitted code, protect themselves from malicious users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express

I am working on a little project for me and my buddies that works like some of these sites like [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/) and [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/). These sites have code editors that you can actually run your code. I want a user to be able to input a function that solves an algorithm and unit test it to see whose code was the most efficient.

**How do sites like this make sure that someone doesn't run a bunch of code that can perform something malicious?**

I think I am having trouble finding answers to this since I don't really know how someone could use that to create problems for a site like CodeWars.

**What are best practices for a web code editor to protect my site from anyone with nefarious intentions (other than cross site scripting)? What are some methods people could exploit a feature like this?**

Comment: Far too broad in scope for this site. See [What kinds of question should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Adding the final paragraph asking about tools is also off topic. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), specifically the section with the numbered list on that page.

Comment: @kenokay, no problem! should I remove the question?

Comment: *Far too broad in scope* means *isn't appropriate for this site*. You can take it down, or leave it to be closed and collect downvotes in the meantime. Up to you.

Comment: okay, thanks! Still figuring this stuff out.

Comment: The links I posted should help. So might taking the [tour] and reading some more in the [help]. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the user's code is executed in an isolated environment (i.e. virtual machine). If so, the code executed will not be able to escape the VM (unless they are able to find vulnerabilities in the VM implementation). The host machines will have the ability to limit resources available to users' programs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several strategies to achieve this.

Basically, the goal is to restrict access to sensitive functions or to virtualize or jail the execution environment for each code execution.

Some server language engines ([such as PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)) accept modules or features which allows to restrict calls to certain sets of functions.

Nowadays with technologies such as docker it is a lot easier to perform fully-featured code execution in any language, with a certain degree of basic security.

Comment: so I am guessing docker will abstract that code that is run away from the rest of your server logic?

Comment: not really, docker does nothing with the code but executes processes by using the features of the `man 7 capabilities` and an AuFS (layered) filesystem in order to simulate an entirely isolated filesystem. The cost of starting a docker container is nearly the cost of starting a process.